# The alternative to Option '--update' in BSD command 'mv'

Tags: mv, options

I am reading a book "Linux Command Line",
there's `-u` update option for command `mv` and `cp'

> -u, --update 
>   When moving files from one directory to another, only move files that either don't exist, or are newer than the existing corresponding files in the destination directory.

The option is not included in BSD 'mv' command.

What's the alternative options for `--update`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) instead of `mv` combining these two options:

```
-u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver
--remove-source-files       sender removes synchronized files (non-dir)
```

Comment: What' does `r` stand for? I didn't find an answer in wikipedia and quora.

Comment: In man page: `-r, --recursive             recurse into directories`

Comment: I got it, r in 'rsync' is for 'remote'. ty.

Comment: Right. I hurried and not think about `r` whithout `-`. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The BSD alternative would be

```
[ "$target" -nt "$source" ] || mv "$source" "$target"
```

This performs the `mv` if `$target` does not exist, or if it's not newer than `$source`.